# How to split a string in PowerShell

Tags: regex, string, powershell, split

This seems like it should be fairly simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a string that looks like this:

```
$string = "blah blah; something"
```

All I want to do is break them apart at the semicolon and space, but whenever I try to do it using `$string.split("; ")` it also breaks apart the first half of the string because of the space. I'm assuming that I probably need to use Regex, but don't have a good grasp of that in order to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply splitting the string at `;` and trimming the results from extra whitespace?

```
PS C:\> $string.split(';') | % { $_.trim()}
blah blah
something
```

A regex sure works too:

```
[regex]::split($string, ";\s")
blah blah
something
```

Comment: I hadn't even thought about the trim, that worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`System.String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is designed to split on every character in the string you give it:

```
PS > $string = "blah blah; something"   
PS > $string.Split('; b')  # This splits on ";", " ", and "b"

lah

lah

something    
PS >
```

If you want to split on a pattern such as `"; "`, you should use the [`-split` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx):

```
PS > $string = "blah blah; something"
PS > $string -split '; '
blah blah
something 
PS >
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it doesn't matter in your particular case, you could just remove the second space.

```
$string.Replace("; ", ";").Split(";")
```